# Multiple aar files into single xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my project. I want to use 3 aar files in my project. I am trying to add these aar files into binding project. But binding project allow single aar file only.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings

Comment: The External_Dependency_Id is taken by only from github. But i am having aar file on my local folder